# She wrote to/ him a letter in France

Tags: verbs, ambiguity, transitivity, intransitive-verbs

> **She  wrote him  a letter in  France**
>
> **She wrote to him a letter in  France**

**The  second  sentence is  found  in Oxford Learners  Dictionary.**

I think  there is  some ambiguity  in the  sentences. it  is  not  very  clear  whether  He  or  she is  in  France  or  whether  she  wrote  in French.

Suppose  I say:

1  **She  wrote him  in  France**

2  **She  wrote to  him  in  France.**

I think  the first  sentence   above  may be  wrong

I know that *write* can be used transitively and  intransitively.

Are the  two  sentences in the  first  set   grammatically  cortect?  do  they  differ in  meaning  if  they  are correct?

Here  is  a  link  which  shows the  use  of    **She  wrote  to  him in  France** The  entry  is  found in the Offord Lerners  Dictionary.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/write

Comment: is France used on purpose instead of french?

Comment: @Nikos  Hidalgo.No.  one  of the sentences  is  taken   from an Online  Dictionary.

Comment: The prepositional phrase is a red herring. 'She wrote  him a letter' and 'She wrote a letter to him' are standard; while 'She wrote to him a letter' is not ungrammatical, it sounds like an excerpt from an Austen novel (ie would be seen as pretty weird in conversation or most forms of writing nowadays).

Comment: "She wrote him a letter in France" sounds to me as though the letter-writing  took place in France, rather than the recipient being there, probably because the two words are so close together. You could say "She wrote a letter to him in France" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> She wrote him a letter in France

The way this is structured, it means the subject "she" wrote the letter while "she" was in France. It's somewhat vaguely worded, though, and it could be used to mean that "she" wrote the letter to "him", while "he" was in France. It's not improper, it's just poor grammar elsewhere renders it vague.

> She wrote to him a letter in France

Many Americans would read this as "She wrote him a letter in French", because this way is even more awkward than the previous sentence. "in France" is not clear as to what it is referring to. It sounds like the letter was "in France", but that makes no sense. In American English at least, France and French can sometimes be used interchangeably to refer to the language. It's not proper by any stretch, but it happens.

If you're looking for clarity, make it clear what "in France" means

> She wrote a letter to him while he was in France

Or specify we mean the language, not the country

> She wrote him a letter in French.

Comment: What evidence is there for the claim that 'France and French can sometimes be used interchangeably to refer to the language'?

Comment: @jsw29 Fair question. Most people refer to the language directly, but in France's case, France has its own language. As such, some people will say (mistakenly) "[speaks France](https://www.hltv.org/forums/threads/2119461/do-alex-speak-france)" when they really mean "speaks French".

Comment: I think this is probably due in part to to the fact that French is an atypical English term for a foreign language. Most languages follow the format of `-ish` (Spanish, Polish, etc) or `-an` (Indian, German, Russian, etc)  ending of the word for the people it came from

Comment: The link provided leads one to the sentence 'Do Alex speak France?' A lone example of such a sentence, which was clearly written by someone with very limited knowledge of English, hardly proves that 'France and French can sometimes be used interchangeably to refer to the language'.